# Set up blender for printing/rendering to A4, A3, A2, A1, A0 paper sizes

Tags: rendering, camera

I want to create 3D art to print onto international paper sizes A4, A3, A2 etc.

How do I set up blender (cycles render) to render images at a resolution of 300 pixels/inch which will fit perfectly to the above paper sizes (without stretching)?

Comment: find out the number of pixels needed for the output you need (there are plenty of online calculators for dpi-pixels) and make that the render size in blender.

Comment: http://www.pixelcalculator.com/index.php?lang=en&dpi1=&FS=6

Comment: In addition to what cegaton posted, if you are going to be doing this a lot you might just want to keep a PDF on your desktop of a table showing the pixel dimensions for each paper size at the most common DPI resolutions. I created such a PDF from [this web page](http://www.benricho.org/size_scale/pixel.html) and I use it all the time. (It's in Japanese, but all you need to understand is the numbers.)

Comment: Oops, wrong link. The one in my previous post is also usable, but [this is the one I meant to post](http://www.a-ain.net/2click/pc/pc_082siryo_yosi.html). It has a simpler, cleaner layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.papersizes.org/a-paper-sizes.htm

Simple math:

1.) Get paper size from link above... e.g. A4 = 8.27" x 11.7"

2.) Multiply the dimensions by 300... e.g. A4 = 2481 x 3510

3.) Plug values into the **Properties >> Dimensions >> Resolution** and set scale to 100%

[image]

**NOTE**: You will need a printer that is capable of edge to edge printing.

Comment: Don't forget bleed. Quarter inch for bleed cuts etc.